# Reading label positions from attribute fields with Python in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to label a shapefile with coordinates from attribute table with pyqgis.

I've been messing around with labeling shapefiles with python, I can do most things that I need, but the main setting still eludes me. How do I set data defined coordinates with python from attribute table (label_x, label_y).

Below is just a sample code for triggering labels but it does not have anything in it to trigger labels from coordinates.

```
myLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test_poligon')[0]    
settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.fieldName = "Fid"
settings.placement = 3
settings.enabled = True
settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)
myLayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
myLayer.setLabeling(settings)
myLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Hi @anjisa, try settings.Positionx = "Lon" settings.Positiony= "Lat" if your coordinates are in fields called Lat and Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [QgsProperty()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProperty.html) and [QgsPropertyCollection()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyCollection.html) classes to set the data defined properties. The enum property value `9` and `10` are for the X and Y positions respectively which are listed ([here under "Property"](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html)):

```
myLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test_poligon')[0]

#Create Property Collection
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('qpc')

#Set data-defined properties for X-position
x_prop = QgsProperty()
x_prop.setField("label_x")
pc.setProperty(9, x_prop)

#Set data-defined properties for Y-position
y_prop = QgsProperty()
y_prop.setField("label_y")
pc.setProperty(10, y_prop)

#Apply settings
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
settings.enabled = True
settings.fieldName = "Fid"
settings.placement = 3
settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)
myLayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
myLayer.setLabeling(settings)
myLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is very elegant, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @anjisa - Most welcome, glad it helped :)